# Download html files from cloudkit

Tags: html, xcode, swift, cloudkit

I newbie in xcode, and dont know how change code to succes, here's my code, could s1 help me, change it to download html/css/js documents from cloud kit, and have access to them.

```
                   let photo =
                        record.objectForKey("photo") as! CKAsset

                        let image = UIImage(contentsOfFile:
                            photo.fileURL.path!)

                        self.imageView.image = image
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no difference between reading a photo and reading HTML from CloudKit. CloudKit works fro every kind of file.

For more info about CloudKit, visit the following link:

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/General/Conceptual/iCloudDesignGuide/DesigningforCloudKit/DesigningforCloudKit.html

Comment: Could you write, function  func documentPicker(controller: UIDocumentPickerViewController, didPickDocumentAtURL url: NSURL) and how should i change my code?

Answer (score 0):

html/css/js documents are no different from an image. They are just files. So your code above will work fine with them i.e. read them from the asset path and then do with them as you wish i.e. copy them to a permanent location for example. Note the Asset URL is temporary and the file will will be removed from it sometime in the future.

Comment: Yeah, everywhere wrote same, but when i'm trying create let webPage = record.objectForKey("webPage") as! CKAsset let page = UIDocument(contentsOfFile  : webPage.fileUrl.path! ) it didnt work